# Query for PFQueryTableViewController

Tags: ios, pfquery, pfquerytableviewcontrolle

I am loading user data from `User` class from Parse into `PFQueryTableViewController`. User class represents data from Facebook. Now, I do not want to load the data into `PFQueryTable` of currently logged in User. All other users data is allowed to be loaded. This is my query but still it loads all data from User class. Any suggestions?

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{ 
PFQuery *query;
//[query whereKey:@"FacebookID" notEqualTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"FacebookID"]];
//[query whereKey:@"username" notEqualTo:[PFUser currentUser].username];
if (self.canSearch == 0) {
    query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
    [query whereKey:@"objectId" notEqualTo:[PFUser currentUser].objectId];
} else {
    query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
    [query whereKey:@"objectId" notEqualTo:[PFUser currentUser].objectId];
    [query whereKey:@"username" matchesRegex:_searchbar.text];
}
[query orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];
// If Pull To Refresh is enabled, query against the network by default.
if (self.pullToRefreshEnabled) {
    query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly;
}
// If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
// and then subsequently do a query against the network.
if (self.objects.count == 0) {
    query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
}
return query;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is, you are setting this constraint `[query whereKey:@"FacebookID" notEqualTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"FacebookID"]]` **before** initializing your query. Move the line **below** the initialization code, and it will work.

**Sample corrected code:**

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
[query whereKey:@"FacebookID" notEqualTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"FacebookID"]];
//[query whereKey:@"FacebookID" notEqualTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
if (self.canSearch != 0) {
    [query whereKey:@"username" matchesRegex:_searchbar.text];
}
[query orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];
// If Pull To Refresh is enabled, query against the network by default.
if (self.pullToRefreshEnabled) {
    query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly;
}
// If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
// and then subsequently do a query against the network.
if (self.objects.count == 0) {
    query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
}
return query;
}
```

**Alternative:**

All Parse classes have a unique key, the `objectId`. I suggest you use this as a constraint in your query.

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {

    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query]; // [PFUser query] is same as [PFQuery queryWithClassName@"_User"]
    [query whereKey:@"objectId" notEqualTo:[PFUser currentUser].objectId];
    [query whereKey:@"username" matchesRegex:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"^%@", _searchBar.text] modifiers:@"i"]; // Case insensitive search

    // ...other code...

    return query;
}
```